# Ordenar uma lista alfanumérica por numero

Tags: python, lista

Para fins de estudo, tenho o seguinte problema:

> Uma lista com compras de supermercado com descrição e valores , preciso ordenar de forma crescente mas sem perder a descrição.

Obs.: Para ordenar os itens tenho que criar as funções, não posso utilizar prontas.

Exemplo:

```
Lista = ["pao" , "2.50" , "queijo" , "3.00", "leite", "2.00"]
Lista_ordenada = ["leite","2.00" ,"pao" , "2.50" , "queijo" , "3.00"]
```

Pensei em utilizar *bubble sort* sempre comparando índices par, mas não consegui.

Comment: Mas você tem uma lista de *strings* onde algumas são descrições e outras são valores? No mínimo, diria que é uma estrutura bem esquisita. Provavelmente uma lista de tuplas representaria melhor seus dados. Você que definiu essa lista ou obteve de algum lugar?

Comment: é um exercício,
eu tenho que informar a descrição e o valor.

sei que poderia usar dicionario, chave e valor, mas nesse caso não posso, tenho que fazer usando apenas lista mesmo.

Comment: Então mude a estrutura que armazena os dados. Colocar dados de naturezas distintas em uma mesma lista só adicionará complexidade ao seu problema e diminuirá semântica/legibilidade/manutenibilidade de sua aplicação

Comment: Anderson, eu entendo isso, 
mas é um exercício que me foi passado , e eu queria resolver.

sei que em uma aplicação real, não vou utilizar dessa forma.

Comment: Então coloque o enunciado do exercício completo na pergunta para que as respostas possam lhe trazer a melhor solução possível (e não apenas uma solução a partir do que já fez)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que juntar os valores com as suas descrições. A lista, desse jeito, não possui um *mapeamento* entre o produto e o valor. Você poderia por exemplo fazer tuplas de dois itens: o produto e seu valor.

```
minha_lista = ["pao" , "2.50" , "queijo" , "3.00", "leite", "2.00"]
lista_pares = []
for i in range(0, len(minha_lista), 2):  # Iterar sob a lista em passos de 2
    item = minha_lista[i]
    preco = minha_lista[i + 1]
    lista_pares.append((item, preco))

print(lista_pares)
# [('pao', '2.50'), ('queijo', '3.00'), ('leite', '2.00')]
```

Agora, sim, você pode usar `sorted`:

```
lista_pares_ordenada = sorted(lista_pares, key=lambda tupla: float(tupla[1]))
print(lista_pares_ordenada)
# [('leite', '2.00'), ('pao', '2.50'), ('queijo', '3.00')]
```

E pra transformar a lista de volta a um formato de só strings:

```
lista_ordenada = []
for tupla in lista_pares_ordenada:
    lista_ordenada.append(tupla[0])
    lista_ordenada.append(tupla[1])

print(lista_ordenada)
# ['leite', '2.00', 'pao', '2.50', 'queijo', '3.00']
```

Comment: "*Obs.: Para ordenar os itens tenho que criar as funções, não posso utilizar prontas."* Acho que ele não poderá usar a `sorted` :(

Comment: Obrigado Pedro,
não posso utilizar tuplas , apenas lista , e nem posso usar utilizsar sorted..

mas isso já me da algumas ideias. 
muito obrigado

Comment: Eita, nem tuplas? Exercício muito estranho...

Comment: @EvertonJ.daSilva Ah, não vi a observação, perdão. Mas a grande sacada aqui é agrupar os itens consecutivos da lista em pares, pode ser em outras listas mesmo ao invés de tuplas, e depois ordenar pelo segundo item.